# I cannot modify the json I receive from a web request

Tags: node.js

I am receiving data from a web service that I have done in `nodejs`. My problem is that I want to add a value to the response so that my server returns it.

The result of the request to my database is received by the variable `data` that has a structure like this:

```
 {
        "nombre": "equipo nuevo72",
        "zona_id": "5ee2e241af5b1142d0a85a0e",
        "zona_info": null,
        "tipo_id": "5ee31c449c0b4f4b343f5934",
        "tipo_info": {
        },
        "marca": "EVANGELION3",
        "modelo": "KIA PICANTO3",
        "serie": "serie 123",
        "anio": "2013",
        "identificador": "TUW26D3",
        "fotos": [
            "50117437174.png",
        ],
        "notas": "esta es una nota3",
        "lista_repuestos": [

        ]
 }
```

I want to add a value to it, I would like to add the property `test: '123`. Although `data` is a json, the`test` property is not added. How can I solve that?

```
app.get("/equipo_detalle/:_id", [], function (req, res) {
let body = req.params;
Equipo.findOne({ _id: body._id }, (err, data) => {  ---> data is the response

    if (err) {
    return res.status(200).json({
        ok: false,
        err: { message: err.message },
    });
    }
    data.test = "123";
    res.json({
      ok: true,
      data: data,
    });
  });
});
```

doing that:

```
{ ok: true, data: { ...data, test: '123' } }
```

I am getting:

[image]

NOTE:I am using a mongoose scheme. If I return `data` it does not appear with the rest of the properties that I have not defined.

OUTPUT DESIRED:

```
    {
     . . .
    test:'123'
    }
```

Comment: What is it that you are getting now?

Comment: same object....

Comment: Maybe data has had `Object.freeze()` applied to it from the library? You could try to duplicate data whilst adding your test: `{ ok: true, data: { ...data, test: '123' } }`

Comment: copy data object to another var and then do your modifications on it and return the modified version

Comment: @tHeSiD in my real data, I am getting this.... https://i.imgur.com/A2FvYKw.jpg

Comment: @George  in my real data, I am getting this https://i.imgur.com/hyeVcSy.jpg at the end add `test`

Comment: What library are you using to make the requsts?

Comment: mongoose........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you're working with data returned from an API, it's always best practice to clone the data instead of mutating the response resultset. If you're doing an API request and the request handler returns a JSON object (such as axios or fetch), mutate until your heart is content because it returns JSON.

With other libraries, such as NoSQL request processors (`Equipo` in this case), they may (and occasionally do), apply `Object.freeze` and other functions to prevent object & property mutation. [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) completely locks the object, while [Object.seal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) prevents new properties from being added. You can use `Object.isFrozen()` and `Object.isSealed()` to see if the JSON you have prevents mutations.

If you're using the latest version of Mongoose (>5.0.0), you can use Promises and asynchronous functions to get the data. Mongoose returns a [Document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-toJSON) object from queries, so you can use the helper `toJSON()` to grab the raw data.

```js
app.get("/some/api", (req, res) => {
  const { body } = req.params;
  Equipo.findOne({ _id: body._id })
    .then(data => {
      return res.status(200).json({
        ok: true,
        data: {
          ...data.toJSON(),
          test: "123
        }
     });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return res.status(404).json({ ok: false, err: { message: err.message } });
    });

  // Always do a fail-thru return from here so your API doesn't hang forever
  return res.status(400).json({ ok: false, err: { message: "Invalid response, something bad happened" } });
});
```

What we're doing in our success return is cloning the object using the `Object.spread` operator. If you are using a version of NodeJS that doesn't support this, you can use `Object.assign` instead, eg.

```
return res.status(200).json({
  ok: true,
  data: Object.assign({}, data.toJSON(), { test: "123" })
});
```

[The spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) allows us to create a new object from existing values, which is comparably to a very shallow clone, while [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) copies values and properties from n-number objects onto the target object, the first argument in `Object.assign`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks friend, but same problem...  `data: Object.assign({}, data, { test: "123" })`

Comment: So you want to take the data under the `"$__"` property?

Comment: when I do a `console.log (data)` what I need appears (initial structure) I just want to add `test` to it

Comment: Can you try `data.toObject()`?

Comment: @yavg updated answer with `.toJSON()`. I've tested this with my own local script, it should run for you.

Comment: what is the secret of? .toJSON()?

Comment: I had to play around with it to see what was happening, but according to the docs, Mongoose returns a `Document` object, which exposes `toObject()` and `toJSON()`. `toJSON()` returns the object in JSON format (eg. {id: "1}) without anything else attached - which is what you need.

Comment: can you just simply do like: res.json({
      ok: true,
      data: {data,test:'123'}
    })

Comment: Data isn't json, it's an object. When returning it as JSON, nodejs will do its best to transform, but when you're mutating/working with it, you need to transform it to json first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting that your first assumption is not correct:

```
The result of the request to my database is received by the variable data that has a structure like this:

 {
        "nombre": "equipo nuevo72",
        "zona_id": "5ee2e241af5b1142d0a85a0e",
        "zona_info": null,
        "tipo_id": "5ee31c449c0b4f4b343f5934",
        "tipo_info": {
        },
        "marca": "EVANGELION3",
        "modelo": "KIA PICANTO3",
        "serie": "serie 123",
        "anio": "2013",
        "identificador": "TUW26D3",
        "fotos": [
            "50117437174.png",
        ],
        "notas": "esta es una nota3",
        "lista_repuestos": [

        ]
 }
```

You can log that out to see, If that's the case, then you can just extract the data you need out & return it.

Comment: if I return `data`, it returns exactly that. but I am unable to add new property like `test` case

Comment: The returned data might go through other processing layers, we better keep it local and log it out.

Comment: What do you mean? I am not logged in. this is from the backend. excuse my ignorance, I don't know how I can solve it.

Comment: Before this line: `data.test = "123"`;  You can add `console.log(data)` and see it in your console.

Answer (score 0):

just do:

```
res.json({
      ok: true,
      data: {data,test:'123'}
    });
```

Comment: I want to add it to the data variable